# Div Background not showing up what's the solution?

Tags: html, css, materialize

Why my background color in the circles class is not working? Been trying this for about 5 minutes what's wrong ?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Simon Game</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Simon Game.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s6">
                <div id="circle1" class="circles"></div>
                <div id="circle2" class="circles"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col s6">
                <div id="circle3" class="circles"></div>
                <div id="circle4" class="circles"></div>    
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="Simon Game.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.circles {
    color: black;
    background: black;
}
```

Comment: Maybe because your `div`'s are empty and have no width or height. Have you tried adding a width and height?

Comment: Please add some content to that div

Comment: Just now tried not working.

Comment: @YaserAliPeedikakkal Lemme try;.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/genax5og/

Answer (score 2):

If the container doesn't have any content then you should provide some fixed height and width in order to see the styles, try this

```
.circles {
    color: black;
    background: black;
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The property is called `background-color`. Also if you have no text inside your element, you need to set a `width` and `height` so it shows up.

Fixed CSS:

```
.circles {
    color: black;
    background-color: black;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Still no luck.;

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with width and height, they dont have any content.

```css
.circles {
    color: black;
    background: black;
     width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s6">
                <div id="circle1" class="circles"></div>
                <div id="circle2" class="circles"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col s6">
                <div id="circle3" class="circles"></div>
                <div id="circle4" class="circles"></div>    
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

NOW this may help you .

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s6">
                <div id="circle1" class="circles"></div>
                <div id="circle2" class="circles"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col s6">
                <div id="circle3" class="circles"></div>
                <div id="circle4" class="circles"></div>    
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="Simon Game.js"></script>
</body>

#circle1 {
    color: black;
    background-color: red;
    height:50px;
    width:150px;
}

#circle2 {
    color: black;
    background-color: green;
    height:50px;
    width:150px;
}

#circle3 {
    color: black;
    background-color: black;
    height:50px;
    width:150px;
}

#circle4 {
    color: black;
    background-color: blue;
    height:50px;
    width:150px;
}
```

Comment: All the divs have the class circles. I want to change the background of all of them.

Comment: There is not a problem with background property or color issue. The only problem with width and height.

Comment: please dont add the picture of fiddle as well. Try to insert the fiddle.

Comment: @AbdullahDanyal i removed the pic ..remove the negative